# How do i replace the character '...' in certain values of columns in dataframe . The number of '.' is not fixed .

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this Energy table dataframe having some values of energy supply column as '...', with no fixed number of this character. The values are all numeric . I want to replace those characters. Here's what I have used :

```
vn['Energy Supply'].astype(str)
for x in vn['Energy Supply']:
     if x.startswith('.'): 
           x.replace(0, inplace= True)
```

The '.astype' also doesn't change the dtype to str

Comment: You need to assign it back to the column. `vn['Energy Supply'] = vn['Energy Supply'].astype(str)`. `astype` doesn't modify data in place but return a new Series.

Answer (score 4):

Since you use `startswith` seems like you are looking for something like this :

```
vn['Energy Supply']=vn['Energy Supply'].astype(str)
vn['Energy Supply'].replace(r'^\.+',value=0,inplace=True,regex=True)
```

Using for loops for dataframes is however a bad idea .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.to_numeric`

```
vn['Energy Supply'] = pd.to_numeric(vn['Energy Supply'], 'coerce').fillna(0)
```